# Trigger.io video opening in separate app

Tags: android, video, trigger.io

I'm developing a Trigger.io app for Android. I have a button which, when tapped, should play a video:

```
  $( '#button-video' ).click(function() {
      forge.media.videoPlay('video/placeholder-vid.mp4',
            function () {
            },
            function (error) {                        
            }
        );
    }
  );
```

However, when I click the button, the button attempts to launch an external app to play the video (MX Player in my case).

Is this the expected behaviour for a Trigger.io video in an Android app?

If not, how can I get this video to play within the app itself?

I'm testing on a Nexus 7 with 4.2.2, using the latest version of Trigger.io (v2.1.4).

Answer (score 0):

Check your application preferences. You may have configured MX Player to be the default app to play videos on your device. You can reset the preferences by going to Settings > Apps > ... > Reset app preferences (the ... is the menu / option button either in top bar or hardware button).